# CodeIgniter search form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, search

I am currently learning CodeIgniter and I am looking to develop a simple example consisting of 2 forms, let’s call them form a and form b. Form a has one edit field called “LastName” and form b will displays a list of all names in a table matching the value in “LastName” something like

`select first_name, last_name from my_table where last_name = :LastName`

I need this example to understand the mechanisms of passing variables from one form and controller to another. I am guessing this is using a method like $_POST but no examples on the web look very clear.

Comment: Are forms gonna be on the same page? If so - I can only think about AJAX way of doing that. If you wanna show 1 form on 1 page and then user would click button and results would show up on another page - u can use just PHP. plz. specify how u want it to work.

Comment: form and result will be on separate pages; it must use CodeIgniter

Comment: Then you are asking about how to use CI to do forms, which is well WELL covered in their own docs.

Comment: I am sorry DampeS8N but that is not a very useful answer

Answer (score 1):

So you would have a form...

```
<form action="/controller/name/" method="post">
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Then in your controller (assuming your already connected to the database):

```
function index() {

    // This is the last name from the form
    $LastName = $this->input->post('LastName');

    // Create the query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name = ?";

    // Execute it, replacing the ? with the last name from the form
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($LastName));

    // Show results
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
       echo $row->first_name . "<br />";
       echo $row->last_name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks fire; At a minimum, do I need one controller or two?

Comment: it depends on what you are trying to do, a controller is really a page it is important that you understand the terminology read the CI user guide from the beginning it's very easy to understand

Comment: I think I need 2 controllers (for 2 pages), one for the input form (page) and another for the display page. In your example the two are merged together; what is the best way to separate them?

Comment: yes that would work fine! please click on the tick to mark this as the expected answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your view folder: application/view/form_a.php,  application/view/forma_b.php

Your controller folder:  application/controller/controller_name.php

Your model folder: application/model/related_model_name.php

Your controller_name.php file:

```
 class Controller_name extends Controller
{

function index()
{
  $this->load->view('form_a'); //this loads the form  
}

function results()
{
  $name= $this->post->input('last_name');
  $this->load->model('related_model_name'); //this is the model to fetch the data
  $data['names']= $this->related_model_name->searchByLastName($name);
  if(!empty($data))
  $this->load->view('form_b', $data);
}


}//eoc
```

Your related_model_name.php file

```
class Related_model_name extends Model

{
function __construct()
{
 parent::Model(); 
}

function searchByLastName($name)

{
 $query = $this->db->get_where('table_name', array('last_name'=>$name)); 
 if($query->nu_rows() > 0)
 return $query->results(); 
}//eof

}//eoc
```

Your form_b.php view file

do a print_r($data) and that should give you an idea of how to display the data. 
it maybe something like

```
foreach ($names as $name)
{
 echo $name->name; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this thread is old, but I am new to CodeIgniter and have been working with a similar challenge. My challenge is to create a search form that finds growers in a specific zip code. Here is my solution. It's simpler than I expected and might help someone else.

This code assumes you are connected to your database and have a standard MVC CI application, etc.

I handle most of this task in the model and view, but I do have this method in my controller:

```
public function result()
    {
        $zipcode = $this->input->post('zip_code');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('growers', array('zip LIKE' => $zipcode));
        return $query->result_array();  
    }
```

In my model, I used the following method:

```
public function result()
    {
        $zipcode = $this->input->post('zip_code');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('growers', array('zip LIKE' => $zipcode));
        return $query->result_array();  
    }
```

I have three views -- one page (located in views/pages/search.php), and two widgets --one for the search form and one for the search results (located in views/widgets/result).

I have the search result form on the same page that the results display. However, each section is contained in its own view file, which I have placed in views/widgets. The code for this section in the page view is:

```
    <div class="search" style="margin-top:0px;">
            <?php 
                $this->load->view('widgets/search');
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="results">
        <div id="grower-info">
            <?php
                $this->load->view('widgets/result');            
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The search form widget is:

```
<form action="search-results" method="post">        
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="zip_code" value="zip code" size="10">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
```

The search result widget is:

```
<?php

$results = $this->pages_model->result();
 foreach ($results as $result)
 {
    echo '<h4>'.$result['company'].'</h4>';
    echo $result['address_1'] . ' ' . $result['address_2'].'<br>';
    echo $result['city'].', ' . $result['state'] . '  ' . $result['zip'].'<br>';
    echo 'Phone:  ' . $result['office_phone'].'<br>';
    echo 'Fax:  ' . $result['office_fax'].'<br>';
    echo 'Website:  <a href="'.$result['website'].'" target="_blank">' . $result['website'].'</a><br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<hr>';    
}

if (count($results) < 1) {
    echo 'No results found. Please try your search again, or try <a href="another-search">another search</a>.';
}
?>
```

I hope that helps someone!